# Detect when user accesses the site

Tags: users

I would like to perform an actoin if the user's last access time was last month.

Would this be through [hook_user()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_user/6), when `$op` is equal to "after_update"?

I assume the last access variable would be updated, and I could check.

Comment: Do you mean that when a uses logs in, you want to check if his previous login was more than a month ago?

Comment: Thanks Marc, yes, but as I understand checking access time can be more accurate, as a user may not necessarily logout for a week, but still come back and "access" the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal saves the timestamp of a user's last access, but by the time your can react to a user visiting the site, that value has already been overwritten with the current timestamp (that happens in [sess_write()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--session.inc/function/sess_write/6)). I don't have a cut-and-paste solution for you, but there are some ideas how to store the previous timestamp for later use in this [forum topic](http://drupal.org/node/54144).